# Special characters in node.js readdir()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm running this piece of code in node.js in order to see the files in a directory an to see the stats for them:

```js
var getFiles = function (dir, done) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var pending = files.length;
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      fullPath = dir + "/" + file;
      console.log(fullPath);
      fs.stat(fullPath, function (err, stat) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Stat error");
        } else if (stat && stat != undefined) {
          console.log("Success");
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

My problem is with file names containing special characters. I'm swedish, so there are lots of å, ä and ö. The output from fullPath is correct when it's outputting most filenames, but whenever the filename contains a special character, that character is displayed as "?", and then fs.stat fails cause it cannot find the file. What have I missed? I'm running version v0.5.7 on Windows.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that Windows encodes filenames as ISO-whatever but node reads them as utf8. Try using [iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) to convert from iso to utf8.