# how to deal with special characters in nodejs fs readdir function

Tags: node.js, encoding, special-characters, readdir

I'm reading a directory in nodejs using the `fs.readdir()` function. You feed it a string containing a path and it returns an array containing all the files inside that directory path in string format. It does not work for me with special characters (like `ï`).

*I came across [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738430/special-characters-in-node-js-readdir), however I am on OS X).*

First I created a new dir called `encoding` and created a file called `maïs.md` (with my editor Sublime Text).

```
fs.readdir('encoding', function(err, files) {
  console.log(files);                                   // [ 'maïs.md' ]
  console.log(files[0]);                                // maïs.md
  console.log(files[0] === 'maïs.md');                  // false
  console.log(files[0] == 'maïs.md');                   // false
  console.log(files[0].toString('utf8') === 'maïs.md'); // false
});
```

The above test works correctly for files without special characters. How can I compare this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you character seems to be [this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ef/index.htm). You should try with

```
(1) console.log(files[0] == 'ma\u00EF;s.md'); 
(2) console.log(files[0] == 'mai\u0308;s.md');
```

If (1) works it could mean that the file containing your code is not saved in utf-8 format, so the node.js engine does not interpret correctly the ï character in your code.

If (2) works it could mean that the file system gives to the node engine the ï character in its decomposed unicode form (i followed by a diacritic ¨). cf @thejh answer

In this (2) case, use the [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm) library available on npm to normalize the strings before comparing them (or the original [UnicodeNormalizer](http://coderepos.org/share/browser/lang/javascript/UnicodeNormalizer))

Comment: unfortunately that also does not work (logs false), Sublime Text is configured to use UTF8 for new files, but I thought that only goes for the content and not the filename?

Comment: can you output the value of encodeURIComponent(files[0]) and encodeURIComponent('maïs.md') ; that might give a hint as to whether @thejh pointed you in the right direction (composed unicode chars)

Comment: just using console.log I get `mai%CC%88s.md` for the files[0],
`ma%C3%AFs.md` for the one copied from the literal one. Seems like whe're getting somewhere!

Comment: ok %CC%88 is the utf8 representation of the "combining diaeresis ¨" (\u0308). So it seems your problem is indeed a "unicode normalization" issue just as @thejh hinted.

Comment: the `unorm` library for node does indeed exactly fix my problem! Thanks a lot for pointing me to it! `unorm.nfc(files[0]) === 'maïs.md' // true`

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10484/23863 looks relevant – it's probably because there are different ways to express ï in utf8.

Comment: this looks really tricky. What I want to achieve: match filenames from a directory to those stored elsewhere. I guess I need to find out how to change different composed states.

Answer (score 0):

When reading file and folder names the UTF encoding (UTF-16 on MacOS) is different from the string encoding in the script (UTF-8).

There is a native [String.prototype.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method that will normalize both strings.

In your example just call .normalize() on both strings:

```
console.log(files[0].normalize() === 'maïs.md'.normalize());
```